# Le eriche vengono o venivano chiamate "erici" in qualche parte d'Italia?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Coprono l'altura collinosa, boschetti, pini giganti, cipressi snelli e rigonfi di raccolta rameggiatura, palme sontuosamente frangiate, giocondi frutteti, orti ben coltivati, boschetti di **erici**, e fontanelle ad ogni passo.

Dal contesto, posso immaginare che con "boschetti di erici" l'autrice intenda "boschetti di eriche", ma non ho trovato conferma a questa ipotesi su Internet. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste dirmi se le eriche vengono oppure venivano (dato che la narratrice è Isabella d'Este, la scrittrice usa spesso un linguaggio arcaico) chiamate "erici" in qualche parte d'Italia?

Comment: In latino classico la pianta veniva chiamata _erīce_, però è comunque femminile e ha plurale in _-ae_. Magari la Bellonci (visto che non trovo quest'uso altrove) l'ha italianizzato, da cui il plurale _erici_? (immagino però, pronunciato con la "i" breve, propria di _eriche_)

Comment: Boschetti di eriche? Si tratta di un arbusto che non arriva al metro e mezzo.

Comment: Nell'opera «I Benefattori dell'umanità; ossia Vite e ritratti degli uomini d'ogni paese e d'ogni condizione i quali hanno acquistato diritto alla pubblica riconoscenza» di Melchior Missirini (seconda metà dell'Ottocento) si usa «l'erici»: https://books.google.it/books?id=wULhKViOfS8C&pg=PA614&lpg=PA614&dq=boschetti+di+ericio&source=bl&ots=Vwn_7EmNFq&sig=Hmj_0WEwn8lC33PAM2dKzZx1Xoc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUi5C0yZXWAhXIDcAKHWH7AGEQ6AEIJzAE#v=onepage&q=L'erici&f=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Erici" è il plurale di "erice", leggi dalla definizione:
https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=ERICE100. Secondo questo dizionario, si tratta di una variante arcaica di "erica".

Come ha menzionato @DaG, anche il dizionario Devoto-Oli riporta “èrice” come variante arcaica di “erica”.

Comment: No, il link conferma che è il plurale di _erice_, variante arcaica (derivata sempre dal latino) di _erica_.

Comment: Hai ragione... sorry

Comment: Non preoccuparti :) modifica la risposta e sicuramente verrà accettata.

Comment: Giusto perché sono sempre un po' scettico nei confronti dei dizionari in rete fatti da chissà chi, soprattutto se come in questo caso Treccani e Zingarelli non confermano, ho controllato e posso attestare che almeno il Devoto-Oli riporta “èrice” come variante arcaica di “erica”.

Answer (score 1):

Soltanto per aggiungere una fonte in rete più
autorevole di quella che appare nella risposta di Marco, vorrei dire che anche il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000251.jpg) riporta il termine "erice" come variante arcaica di "erica" e fa un esempio di uso di "erice" in un opera rinascimentale di [Alessandro Citolini](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00086.jpg):

> **Èrica** (ant. *èrice*),  sf.  Bot.  Genere  di  piante fruticose 
>     o  suffruticose  della  famiglia  Ericacee, 
>   con  piccole  foglie  aghiformi,  riunite  in  numero di  cinque  o  sei  in  verticilli;  fiori  solitari  o  in ombrelle  o  in  spighe  ascellari  o  terminali,  con calice  quadripartito,  corolla  urceolata  o  cilin­drica con quattro piccoli lobi; frutto a capsula; l'*Erica  scoparia*, e l'*Erica  arborea* sono diffuse 
>   nell’Italia  centro-meridionale  (i  fusti  e  i  rami servono  per  far  scope,  le  radici  per  fare  pipe); l'*Erica  carnea*, propria dei boschi e dei pascoli delle Alpi e degli Appennini settentrionali, è un arbusto  prostrato, con foglie acuminate e fiori 
>   rosei in racemi o in capolini. 
>         *Citolini,* 210:  L’erice,  l’asiacanta, il ribes.